# what is the NDC logs and how we can use it in our application and what is the significance of that

Tags: java, struts

what is the NDC logs and how we can use it in our application and what is the significance of that...

Answer (score 6):

Nested Diagnostic Contexts are particular to a thread.

Common uses are for recording info *per-session* (if one thread is used for a session), so you can log the originating client, username etc. and other cross-cutting attributes without:

1. passing these attributes through the layers of your application
2. explicitly logging them in each log statement. Log4j will output the NDC if `PatternLayout` is suitably configured.

See also Log4j's Mapped Diagnostic Contexts.

Answer (score 3):

NDC stands for "Nested Diagnostic Contexts", it's a feature of log4j. The most common usage of log4j is just to log stuff without any indication of what client request it was part of, with the result that, when your application runs in production with concurrent requests, all the log messages for all the requests are jumbled together in the log file and telling who did what is impossible. NDC allows you to mark log messages as belonging to particular clients so that you can distinguish who is doing what, without having separate loggers for each client.

Answer (score 3):

Logger are usually *statically* defined in the code, which make log sometimes hard to understand.

The [NDC](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html) allows the *dynamically* `push` a parameter that will be displayed in every subsequent log line issued by the thread, until it is `pop`ped.

Useful if you want a log like:

```
[request=x] a
[request=y] a
[request=x] b
[request=x] c
[request=y] b
[request=x] d
[request=y] c
[request=y] d
```

(Disclaimer: I don't remember the exact formatting)

With just `a,b,c,d` it's hard to understand which thread does what. If you `push` and `pop` the request id dynamically, then it's easier to follow. Can also be used for other kinds of contextual information.